# converting from Jmockit to Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, jmockit

I'm trying to convert a method from Jmockit to mockito framework, not able to execute it.
Added relevant dependencies and @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), working for other methods in the same class.

```
public class MavenUtilTest {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
  @Mock
  private KitLogger log;
  @Mock
  MavenProject mavenProject;
  @Mock
  BuildPluginManager pluginManager;
  @Test
  //Jmockit
  public void testCallMavenPluginWithGoal(@Mocked BuildPluginManager pluginManager) throws PluginConfigurationException, MojoFailureException, MojoExecutionException, PluginManagerException {
        // Given
        MavenProject mavenProject = getMavenProject();
        MavenSession mavenSession = getMavenSession();

        MavenUtil.callMavenPluginWithGoal(mavenProject, mavenSession, pluginManager, "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:help", log);

        // Then
        new Verifications() {{
            pluginManager.executeMojo(mavenSession, (MojoExecution)any);
            times = 1;
        }};
    }
}
```

```
//mockito
  @Test
    public void testCallMavenPluginWithGoal() throws PluginConfigurationException, MojoFailureException, MojoExecutionException, PluginManagerException {
        // Given
        MavenProject mavenProject = getMavenProject();
        MavenSession mavenSession = getMavenSession();
        // When
        MavenUtil.callMavenPluginWithGoal(mavenProject, mavenSession, pluginManager, "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:help", log);
        // Then
        verify(pluginManager,Mockito.times(1)).executeMojo(mavenSession,any(MojoExecution.class));

    }
```

Comment: Are you using JUnit4 or JUnit5? Runners come from Junit4 and Extensions from Junit5. Rules don't exist in JUnit5. What do you mean by "not able to execute it."? Compile-time error? Runtime error? What error message do you see?

Comment: @Lesiak Sorry! I'm using Junit4 and removed @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class).I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: It's not clear this is your problem, but I would not mix Mockito and JMockit tests in the same test class.  You cannot send a JMockit 'mock' to Mockito (and vice-versa).  Mixing the two in a class is just going to cause you headaches.

Comment: @JeffBennett I got it, Let me rework on these.Thanks